# Python: Graph using NetworkX and mplleaflet

Tags: python, graph, leaflet, networkx

I have a networkx graph created from edges such as these:

```
user_id,edges
11011,"[[340, 269], [269, 340]]"
80973,"[[398, 279]]"
608473,"[[69, 28]]"
2139671,"[[382, 27], [27, 285]]"
3945641,"[[120, 422], [422, 217], [217, 340], [340, 340]]"
5820642,"[[458, 442]]"
```

**Example**

[image]

Where the edges are a user's movements between clusters, identified by their cluster label, e.g., `[[340, 269], [269, 340]]`. This represents a user's movement from `cluster 340` to `cluster 269` and then back to `cluster 340`. These clusters have coordinates, stored in another file, in the form of latitude and longitude, such as these:

```
cluster_label,latitude,longitude
0,39.18193382,-77.51885109
1,39.18,-77.27
2,39.17917928,-76.6688633
3,39.1782,-77.2617
4,39.1765,-77.1927
```

Is it possible to link the edges of my graph to their respective cluster in physical space using the node/cluster's lat/long and not in the abstract space of a graph? If so, how might I go about doing so? I would like to graph this on a map using a package such as `mplleaflet` (like shown here: http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/jwass/mplleaflet/master/examples/readme_example.html) or directly into QGIS/ArcMap.

**EDIT**

I'm attempting to convert my csv with cluster centroid coordinates into a dictionary, however, I've run into several errors. Mainly, `NetwotkXError: Node 0 has no position` and `IndexError: too many indices for array.` Below is how I'm trying to convert to a dict and then graph with `mplleaflet`.

```
import csv
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import mplleaflet


g = nx.Graph()

# Set node positions as a dictionary
df = pd.read_csv('G:\Programming Projects\GGS 681\dmv_tweets_20170309_20170314_cluster_centroids.csv', delimiter=',')
df.set_index('cluster_label', inplace=True)
dict_pos = df.to_dict(orient='index')
#print dict_pos

for row in csv.reader(open('G:\Programming Projects\GGS 681\dmv_tweets_20170309_20170314_edges.csv', 'r')):
    if '[' in row[1]:       #
        g.add_edges_from(eval(row[1]))

# Plotting with matplotlib
#nx.draw(g, with_labels=True, alpha=0.15, arrows=True, linewidths=0.01, edge_color='r', node_size=250, node_color='k')
#plt.show()

# Plotting with mplleaflet
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g,pos=dict_pos,node_size=10)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g,pos=dict_pos,edge_color='gray', alpha=.1)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(g,dict_pos, label_pos =10.3)
mplleaflet.display(fig=ax.figure)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is quite easily possible. Try something along this lines.
Create a dictionary, where the node (cluster_label) is the key and longitude latitude are saved as values in a list. I would use pd.read_csv() to read the csv and then use the df.to_dict() to create the dictionary. It should look like this for example:

```
 dic_pos = {u'0': [-77.51885109, 39.18193382],
 u'1': [-76.6688633, 39.18],
 u'2': [-77.2617, 39.1791792],
 u'3': [-77.1927, 39.1782],
 .....
```

Then plotting the graph on a map is as easy as:

```
import mplleaflet

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(GG,pos=dic_pos,node_size=10,node_color='red',edge_color='k',alpha=.5, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(GG,pos=dic_pos,edge_color='gray', alpha=.1)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(GG,pos=dic_pos, label_pos =10.3)

mplleaflet.display(fig=ax.figure)
```

If it does not produce the expected result try to reverse latitude,longitude.

Comment: I've received an error, `NetworkXError: Node 0 has no position.` Upon printing dic_pos, the dictionary does not provide the results like above. It loos like `{'cluster_label': {0.....}, 'latitude': {0: ....}, 'longitude': {0: ....}}`. I tried `df.T.to_dict()` and I got `{0: {'cluster_label': 0.0, 'latitude': ..., 'longitude': ....}, .....`. How do I format the dict to read as you provided? I tried zipping a list but received errors there too.

Comment: If you share the raw data file (e.g. via dropbox link) maybe I am or others are able to provide you with a fully working example. Anyhow, try to get comfortable with the Python function zip. First, df['pos'] = list(zip(df.lat, df.long)). And then, dict(zip(df.cluster_label,df.pos))

Comment: `df['pos'] = list(zip(df.longitude,df.latitude))` and `dict_pos = dict(zip(df.cluster_label,df.pos))` did the trick! Originally, I had tried zipping the latitude/longitude, but was attempting to do so while transforming to a dict which gave errors. Creating a new column for zipped coords, and then transforming into a dict with the labels and new coords zipped worked. Thank you!