# How to visualize networkx graph on the map with labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, leaflet, networkx

I'm following this answer [Python: Graph using NetworkX and mplleaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433173/python-graph-using-networkx-and-mplleaflet), but cannot modify it to display node labels. This is the code that I'm using.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplleaflet
import networkx as nx

small_graph = nx.Graph()
small_graph.add_node('1')
small_graph.add_node('2')
small_graph.add_node('3')
small_graph.add_node('4')
small_graph.add_edge('1', '2')
small_graph.add_edge('3', '2')
small_graph.add_edge('3', '4')


pos = {'1': [55, 10], '2': [56, 11], '3': [57, 12], '4': [58, 12]}
labels = {'1': 'Node 1', '2': 'Node 2', '3': 'Node 3', '4': 'Node 4'}


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(small_graph,pos=pos,node_size=40,node_color='red',edge_color='k',alpha=.5)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(small_graph,pos=pos,edge_color='gray', alpha=.4)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(small_graph,pos=pos, labels=labels, font_size=10)


plt.show()
# mplleaflet.display(fig=fig)
```

If I use standard `plt.show()` I can see labels displayed properly [image: graph visualization using plt.show()]. However, if I uncomment the last line to display this graph on the map, I'm only getting[image: graph visualization using mplleaflet.display()] It's definitely not the matter of the font size, because tweaking this value does not make any difference. Is this at all possible to achieve this? If not, what alternatives do you recommend?

Comment: Try reversing coordinates: `{'1': [10, 55], '2': [11, 56], '3': [12, 57], '4': [12, 58]}`

Comment: @swatchai Thanks for your answer. It still does not display any labels. It just changes the position of the nodes, but has no effect on the labels

Comment: Might be a a `zorder` issue. What happens if you place a text object with high zorder explicitly, e.g. by adding the following before `plt.show()`: `t = ax.text(55, 10, 'Node 1'); t.set_zorder(1000)`?

Comment: @Paul I can see it working fine for `plt.show()` without modifying zorder. Even with the code that you have provided, it still does not work for `mplleaflet.display(fig=fig)`

Comment: It appears that text objects are not supported by mplleafet: https://github.com/jwass/mplleaflet/issues/6

Comment: @Paul Ah, somehow I have missed that. Thanks for the clarification (if you want to publish this as an answer I can accept it)

Comment: Nah, no worries. I was thinking that showing images must be supported. Hence maybe you can get around the restriction on text by making little subaxes with a png of the text that you want to show.