# Place the networkx graph on top of the mplleaflet map

Tags: networkx

I have a vehicle routing (VRP) model output currently visulized using networkx. In addition, I am trying to place the networkx graph on top of a mplleaflet map, but I came across below problem:

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\mplleaflet\utils.py", line 14, in iter_rings     raise ValueError('Unrecognized code: {}'.format(code)) ValueError: Unrecognized code: S
```

Below is the networx part of the code and the graph.

```
def DrawNetwork():
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    locations = DataProblem()._locations
    # print(locations)
    x = 0
    # for vehicle_id in vlist:
    for vehicle_id in new_vlist:
        n = 0
        e = []
        node = []
        cl=PickupColor(x)
        # print(cl)
        # print(data.num_vehicles)
        # print(this_vehicle.id)
        # print(this_vehicle.routes)
        for i in vehicle_id:
            G.add_node(i, pos=(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]))
            # a= [locations[i][0], locations[i][1]]
            # print(a)
            ################
            node.append(i)
            ################
            if n > 0:
                # print(n)
                # print(vehicle_id.routes[n])
                # print (vehicle_id.routes[n-1])
                u = (vehicle_id[n - 1], vehicle_id[n])
                e.append(u)
                node.append(i)
                G.add_edge(vehicle_id[n - 1], vehicle_id[n])
                # nx.draw(G, nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'), nodelist=node, edgelist=e, with_labels=True,
                #         node_color=cl, width=2, edge_color=cl,
                #         style='dashed', font_color='w', font_size=12, font_family='sans-serif')
            n += 1
        nx.draw(G, nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'), nodelist=node, edgelist=e, with_labels=True,
                node_color=cl, width=2, edge_color=cl,
                style='dashed', font_color='w', font_size=12, font_family='sans-serif')
        x += 1
    # let's color the node 0 in black
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, locations, nodelist=[0], node_color='k')
    plt.axis('on')
```

The "new_vlist" used for drawing networkx is:

```
[[32, 2, 90], [83, 82, 68, 90], [62, 40, 39, 90], [44, 60, 59, 61, 67, 90], [54, 53, 55, 90], [10, 77, 7, 84, 13, 90], [8, 51, 26, 71, 90], [76, 72, 75, 69, 90], [63, 19, 20, 52, 90], [42, 81, 65, 38, 28, 27, 30, 31, 90], [80, 43, 64, 22, 21, 66, 25, 29, 90], [85, 9, 88, 70, 6, 90], [3, 90], [49, 33, 35, 16, 14, 15, 87, 90], [24, 23, 78, 79, 17, 86, 90], [34, 18, 58, 11, 12, 57, 90], [37, 74, 73, 36, 5, 4, 89, 90], [48, 47, 46, 45, 50, 1, 41, 56, 90]]
```

below is the neworkx graph plotted:

[image]

what is the right way to combine networkx graph with mplleaflet map? thanks

Comment: What happens if you simply call `mplleaflet.display()` or `mplleaflet.show()` at the end? E.g. as done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239182/how-to-visualize-networkx-graph-on-the-map-with-labels