# Is it possible to plot networkx graph over openstreet style map image?

Tags: python, mapping, networkx, arcgis, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to plot a network graph of car journeys over a streetmap style map.

I have two dataframes; zones and journeys, which I have used to create a network using Networkx

```
locations = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3],
'latitide':[40.710736,40.556678,40.778363],
'longitude':[-73.962940,-74.189803,-73.943489]})
```

`journeys = pd.DataFrame({'from':[1,1,3], 'to':[2,3,2], 'count':[3,5,2] })`

I now want to plot this over a map. Basemaps package is not suitable as it doesnt show road details and I cannot get arcgis to render images. I am therefore attempting to plot my network graph over an image of the city map.

I have used NetworkX to create a graph of nodes (locations) and edges (journeys)

```
graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(journeys, source = 'from', target = 'to',
                    edge_attr = 'count',create_using = nx.DiGraph())
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G = graph, pos = pos, nodelist = graph.nodes(), 
                    node_color = 'r', alpha = 0.8, node_size = 50)
```

`nx.draw_networkx_edges(G = graph, pos = pos, edge_color='g',alpha=0.2, arrows = False)`

Is it possible to import a png image file and use that as a plot base on which i can plot this network graph? I have attempted to use the arcgis basemaps but none are rendering

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'd stick with mapping tools and not use static images. Those will be too much hassle to grab and maintain scale, etc.

My first stop would be to replicate something like [this `cartopy` example](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/examples/tube_stations.html).

If your mapping requirements go beyond Cartopy, or you want interactivity, a lot of people also really like [`leaflet`](https://leafletjs.com/), a JS library which also has a Python/`matplotlib` interface in `mplleaflet`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433173/python-graph-using-networkx-and-mplleaflet) is an example of a question implementing a map + network that way.

Another option for interacting with `leaflet` is [`folium`](http://python-visualization.github.io/folium/). You can see an example integrating a lot of ideas, including plotting networks in a Folium map, in [this excellent tutorial](https://sustainability-gis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lessons/L2/spatial_network_analysis.html).

Yet another option is [`plotly`](https://plotly.com/python/maps/), which can plot both graphs and maps nicely.

Comment: Thanks @kwinkunks.

I have attempted to follow the 'mplleaflet' example you linked, using the following code. However, this plots my network graph only, with no visual representation of a street map. Do you have any idea as to why?
`fig, ax = plt.subplots()

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G = graph, pos = dict_pos,node_size=10 , node_color='red',alpha=.5)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G = graph, pos = dict_pos, edge_color='g',
                        alpha=0.2, arrows = False)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G = graph ,pos=dict_pos, label_pos =10.3)

mplleaflet.display(fig=ax.figure) `

Comment: If your `dict_pos` looks like theirs then no... I guess that's the first thing I'd double-check.